# How do I make a custom post interface in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

my wordpress blog is about musics, and everytime i post a music in my blog i follow the same routine which is very tiresome. So I want to know how can i speed up the process.

Here's my routine when I'm posting new music to my blog:

1. Go to Media and upload a new picture for the new music.
2. Go to the background post type, and create a new background post type for the new music.
3. go to Posts->add new and attach the previously created background post type and the picture to this post and publish the post after inputting details for this new music.

So these 3 steps are very tiring, because each time i add a new music in my blog i need to follow 3 steps. i want to know if there's a way to put all these steps in one page, this page will have input boxes for media, background post type and add new post.

Please tell me how i can do this. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could have a **plugin**, in admin panel form with fields like `browse` for media, `post type`, additional image `browse`  etc. Then have some dynamic function, which takes this form data in variable and on $_POST creates post/registers metas/media etc. using built in worpress functions.

Might also look at template feature of wordpress, might use it in plugin help with the background thing.

This is just an **example of using Wordpress built in functions to create post**:

```
<?php
function create_posts_from_serialized_array() {

//Inyour case it will be $_POST not these two lines
$dude_wheresmyarray = 'LOCATION OF YOUR UNSERIALISED ARRAY'; //Dude, where's my array?
$original_array = unserialize (file_get_contents($dude_wheresmyarray));      // Load array

// Create categories, return variables containg newly created category ids

$category = array('cat_ID' => '', 'cat_name'=> utf8_encode('Cat1'), 'category_description' => '', 'category_nicename' => 'cat1', 'category_parent' => '');          $cat_id10 = wp_insert_category($category, true);

$aid = 0; //foreach array begin with 0 and ++ later on

foreach ($original_array as $each_array) {

/*
* Variable for new post on left, variable from $original_array on right
*/
$new_post_title = $original_array[$aid]['title'];
$new_post_content = $original_array[$aid]['description'];
$new_category = $original_array[$aid]['category'];
$new_name = $original_array[$aid]['name'];
$new_address = $original_array[$aid]['address'];
$new_phone = $original_array[$aid]['phone'];
$new_web = $original_array[$aid]['web'];
$new_mail = $original_array[$aid]['mail'];

if ($new_category == 'a')    {$assign_cat = $cat_id1;}

/*
* UPDATE POST
*/

$my_post = array();
$my_post['ID'] = ''; // Integer here WORKS ONLY IF THERE ALREADY IS A POST WITH THAT ID!
$my_post['post_type']      = 'post';
$my_post['post_title']      = utf8_encode($new_post_title);
$my_post['post_content']  = utf8_encode($new_post_content);
$my_post['post_status']   = 'publish';
$my_post['post_author']   = 1;
$my_post['post_category'] = array($assign_cat);

$pid = wp_update_post( $my_post ); //Update post, return new post ID

/*
* UPDATE META
*/

update_post_meta($pid, 'name',      utf8_encode($new_name));
update_post_meta($pid, 'address',   utf8_encode($new_address));
update_post_meta($pid, 'phone',     $new_phone);
update_post_meta($pid, 'web',       $new_web);
update_post_meta($pid, 'mail',      $new_mail);

$aid ++; //loopidy loopin

}
}

?>
```